# Dynamic Buttons in Navigation Bar using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

I have a problem...
My VueJS Application using Vuetify.
I have a `<v-toolbar>`, and on the right, I want to place some buttons that change depending on the component shown in `<router-view>`, but i can't access to component properties from $route or $route for get objects and methods bind to model of my component.

I would like to know if there is any way to assign a model to  from my main component.

I have tried with "named-routes" but I do not know what is the way that properties can be shared between components that are managed by an  `<router-view>` and updated live.

In resume:

I have my application skeleton with a navigation bar, additionally in the dynamic content I have a `<router-view>`. Depending on the component that is displayed in `<router-view>`, I would like to see buttons in the navigation bar corresponding to that component, which interact and change the data or execute methods of the component.

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
  <router-view></router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
   return {
    
   };
  }
 };
</script>
```

index.js (router)

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import AppLogin from '@/components/AppLogin'
import Skeleton from '@/components/Skeleton'
import ShoppingCart from '@/components/ShoppingCart'
import ShoppingCartButtons from '@/components/ShoppingCartButtons'
import ProductSelection from '@/components/ProductSelection'
import ProductSelectionButtons from '@/components/ProductSelectionButtons'
import ProductDetail from '@/components/ProductDetail'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path : '/login',
      name : 'AppLogin',
      component : AppLogin
    },
    {
      path : '/app',
      name : 'Skeleton',
      component : Skeleton,
      children : [{
          path : 'shopping-cart',
          components : {
            navigation : ShoppingCart,
            navButtons : ShoppingCartButtons
          }
        }, {
          path: 'product-selection',
          name : 'ProductSelection',
          components : {
            navigation : ProductSelection,
            navButtons : ProductSelectionButtons
          }
        },
        {
          path: 'product-detail',
          name : 'ProductDetail',
          components : {
            navigation : ProductDetail
          },
          props : true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Skeleton.vue

```html
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-navigation-drawer
            persistent
            :mini-variant="miniVariant"
            :clipped="true"
            v-model="drawer"
            enable-resize-watcher
            fixed
            app
            >
            
            <v-list>

            <v-list-tile
                value="true"
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                :to="item.path">

                <v-list-tile-action>
                <v-icon v-html="item.icon"></v-icon>
                </v-list-tile-action>
                
                <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>

        <v-toolbar
            app
            :clipped-left="clipped"
        >
            <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer">
            </v-toolbar-side-icon>
            
            <v-toolbar-title v-text="$route.meta.title"></v-toolbar-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <router-view name="navButtons"></router-view>

        </v-toolbar>
    
        <v-content>
            <router-view name="navigation"/>
        </v-content>

        <v-footer :fixed="true" app>
   <p style="text-align : center; width: 100%">&copy; CONASTEC 2018</p>
  </v-footer>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
 return {
   clipped: true,
   drawer: false,
   fixed: false,
   items: [
  {
    icon: "shopping_cart",
    title: "Carrito de Compras",
    path : "/app/shopping-cart"
  },
  {
    icon: "attach_money",
    title: "Facturas"
  },
  {
    icon: "account_balance_wallet",
    title: "Presupuestos"
  },
  {
    icon: "insert_chart",
    title: "Informes"
  },
  {
    icon: "local_offer",
    title: "Productos"
  },
  {
    icon: "person",
    title: "Clientes"
  },
  {
    icon: "layers",
    title: "Cuenta"
  },
  {
    icon: "comment",
    title: "Comentarios"
  },
  {
    icon: "settings",
    title: "Ajustes"
  }
   ],
   buttons : [],
   miniVariant: false,
   right: true,
   rightDrawer: false
 };
  },
  name: "Skeleton"
};
</script>
```

**EDITED**

My solution is create a new component Toolbar and add slots for buttons to right and left.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <v-navigation-drawer persistent :mini-variant="false" :clipped="true" v-model="drawer" enable-resize-watcher fixed app>
            <v-list>
                <v-list-tile value="true" v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :replace="true" :to="item.path">
    
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                        <v-icon v-html="item.icon"></v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
    
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                        <v-list-tile-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-tile-title>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    
        <v-toolbar app :clipped-left="true" color="primary" :dark="true" flat>
    
            <v-toolbar-side-icon v-if="showDrawer" @click.stop="drawer = !drawer">
            </v-toolbar-side-icon>

            <v-toolbar-side-icon v-if="!!back" @click="back">
                <v-icon>keyboard_backspace</v-icon>
            </v-toolbar-side-icon>
            
            <v-toolbar-title v-text="title" style="font-size: 1.4em"></v-toolbar-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-card-actions>
                <slot name="right"></slot>
            </v-card-actions>
    
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-snackbar
            :timeout="5000"
            :top="true"
            :multi-line="true"
            :vertical="true"
            v-model="snackbar.show"
            >
            {{ snackbar.content }}
            <v-btn flat color="white" @click.native="snackbar.show = false">Cerrar</v-btn>
        </v-snackbar>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app-toolbar',
        props: ['title','showDrawer', 'back'],
        data() {
            return {
                drawer : false,
                items: [{
                    icon: "shopping_cart",
                    title: "Carrito de Compras",
                    path: "/carrito-compras"
                }, {
                    icon: "attach_money",
                    title: "Facturas",
                    path: "/documentos-tributarios"
                }, {
                    icon: "account_balance_wallet",
                    title: "Presupuestos"
                }, {
                    icon: "insert_chart",
                    title: "Informes"
                }, {
                    icon: "local_offer",
                    title: "Productos"
                }, {
                    icon: "person",
                    title: "Clientes"
                }, {
                    icon: "layers",
                    title: "Cuenta"
                }, {
                    icon: "comment",
                    title: "Comentarios"
                }, {
                    icon: "settings",
                    title: "Ajustes"
                }]
            };
        },
        computed : {
            snackbar() {
                return this.$store.getters.snackbar;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and use is:

```html
 <app-toolbar title="Carrito de Compras" :showDrawer="true">
    <template slot="right">
        <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="confirm">
            <v-icon>monetization_on</v-icon>
        </v-toolbar-side-icon>

    </template>
</app-toolbar>
```

Comment: Try using `meta` on your routes. That way you could identify each component served by the router.

Comment: Also, show us your code. Thanks.

Comment: @CENT1PEDE i am edit and this is my code

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing as you in a recent project and found altering the structure was the easier way to fix issues like this.

My structure was as follows:

app.vue: Only contains `<router-view>` no other components

router.js: Parent route is a layout component, all sub routes which contains my toolbars and other layout components and it's own `<router-view>` which receives child routes

ex:

```
{
  path: '/login',
  name: 'Login',
  component: load('login')
},
{
  path: '/',
  component: load('main-layout'),
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'Home Page',
      component: load('homePage')
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'Settings',
      component: load('settings'),
    }
  ]
}
```

Now in your main-layout:

```
computed: {
  showHomeButton () {
    if (this.$route.path === '/') {
      return true
    }
    return false
    // Repeat for other routes, etc...
  },
}
```

Comment: @Brayan you're going to have to be more specific, I'm not sure what you're asking. Usually you send data down to other components with props and up with emit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vuex, you can use [vuex-router-sync](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync), then you can
access the route from any component with `this.$state.route.path`.

If not, Scott's answer is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, My solution was manage the left button action from de meta of vue router like this:

```
    {
      path: '/feedstocks/:categoryId/:id',
      name: 'Feedstock',
      component: () =>
        import(
          /* webpackChunkName: "client-chunk-feedstock-details" */ '@/views/FeedstockDetails.vue'
        ),
      props: true,
      meta: {
        authNotRequired: true,
        backRoute: 'Material'
      }
    }
```

Then I'm able to check that metadata in app bar button action:

```
<v-app-bar app color="primary" dark>
  <v-btn text icon color="white" @click="leftButtonAction">
    <v-icon>{{ leftButtonIcon }}</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <v-toolbar-title>
    {{ currentAppTitle }}
  </v-toolbar-title>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
</v-app-bar>

leftButtonIcon() {
  if (this.$route.meta.backRoute) {
    return 'mdi-chevron-left'
  }
  return 'mdi-menu'
}

leftButtonAction() {
  if (this.$route.meta.backRoute) {
    this.$router.push({ name: this.$route.meta.backRoute })
  } else {
    this.toggleDrawer()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a time for a more up-to-date answer.

For my requirement to dynamically modify the item list in the app-bar based on the selected view, the solution was to use the [Named Views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html)